# Output domain COMPUTERNAME and logged in USERNAME spreadsheet

Tags: windows, active-directory, batch-file

So the boss asked for a spreadsheet that would show him all the computers in our enterprise and the users that are currently logged in.

I stopped asking "why?" and started with NBTSTAT. The <03> results were inconsistent. Then I tried NET CONFIG WORKSTATION, and finally PSLOGGEDON.EXE (SYSINTERNALS). These were good, but I'd have to find a way to pass the results of NET VIEW and format the output nicely for a csv.

But then I thought there must be a better way. 90% of our PCs are WinXP so I could use WMIC or maybe DSQuery. I'd rather isolate the command execution to the workstations in our AD Computers container and not touch our Servers.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Here is what I've go so far: 
for /f "skip=3 delims= \" @@c in ('net view') do echo.@@c >> computer_list.txt 
for /f @@u in (computer_list.txt) do psloggedon -l -x \\@@u 2>nul | find "DOMAIN\" >> user_list.txt

Now I need to merge the two text files into a csv.  I'd like to format it, like this:

ComputerA <tab> LoggedinUser
ComputerB <tab> LoggedinUser
...

Comment: You can put that code directly into your post. That reads nicer. In the comment no one will read it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an LDAP search to Active Directory (LDIFDE)

```
ldifde -m -f OUTPUT.LDF -b USERNAME DOMAINNAME *  -s SERVERNAME -d "cn=users,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=Microsoft,DC=Com" -r "(objectClass=user)"
```

searching users then computers by changing the objectclass.

You can also specify just the attributes you want at the end.

```
eg: ldifde -f e:\Exportuser.ldf -s DomainController -d "ou=user,ou=sitename,dc=uk" -p subtree -r "(objectClass=User)" -l givenname,sn,samaccountname,mail,dn
```

or use a .net script

Answer (score 1):

PsExec.exe + PsLoggedOn.exe + batch file.

Step 1. Download PsExec.exe and put it in a folder.

Step 2. Put PsExec.exer and PsLoggedOn.exe in a folder together.

Step 3. Determine a network share.

Step 4. Create a text file called pc_list.txt with the results of NET VIEW pasted in it (minus the "\" - should be one computer name per line). Basically should be a text with the following:

```
computer1
computer2
computer3
computer4
10.1.1.1
10.2.1.3
10.3.1.4
```

etc.

You can use IP's or Computer names.

Step 5. Create a Batch file called PsExec.bat with the following code:

```
"location_of_PsExec.exe"\PsExec.exe @"location_of_text_file"\pc_list.txt -u domain\Admin_username -p password -n 60 -c -f "location_of_runPsLoggedOn.bat"\runPsLoggedOn.bat
```

Step 6. Create another batch file called runPsLoggedOn.bat with the following code:

```
@echo off
   echo.%computername%>>"location_of_network_share"\userlist.txt
   PsLoggedOn.exe -x>>"location_of_network_share"\userlist.txt
   echo.>>"location_of_network_share"\userlist.txt
```

Step 7. Run the PsExec.bat

This is really probably not going to be the EXACT answer you're looking for, but this should at least get you pointed in the right direction... 
I didn't test this out, but I use something similar to get other things done using PsExec.exe.
You would want to just write in the code to only output the domain\username to the file on your network share, (from PsLoggedOn.exe -x>>"location_of_network_share"\userlist.txt) because the output is like this: 
Users logged on locally:
        domain\user

No one is logged on via resource shares.

You also might want to find, as far as formatting goes, a way to output that username to a variable so that you could do the following:

```
echo.%computername% %variable_username_from_PsLoggedOn%>>"location_of_network_share"\userlist.txt
```

Anyhow, this should get you started on your way to getting this solved...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give me what I want:

```
FOR /F "skip=3 delims=\  " %%A IN ('net view') DO WMIC /Node:"%%A" ComputerSystem Get UserName /Format:csv 2>nul | MORE /E +2 >> computer_user_list.csv
```

Note that there is a tabulator followed by a space after `delims=\`

Maybe someone else could use it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Netscan from [Softperfect](http://www.softperfect.com/)?